# add item into collection for datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I come to you because I have a question (surprising?).

I am currently working with a "Matrix" collection that contains several objects. When I display it in my datagrid, I want an additional data, namely a checkbox (to select my lines in the datagrid).
Could you help me with that?

```
        private ObservableCollection<Matrix> _Matrice;
    public ObservableCollection<Matrix> Matrice
    {
        get
        {
            return _Matrice;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _Matrice)
            {
                _Matrice = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Matrice));
            }
        }
    }

            Matrice = new ObservableCollection<Matrix>(await _dataService.GetMatrice(idMatrice));
```

"Matrice" contains my datas (dates, names, etc.)
If I display it in a datagrid, I get the display of all my data. I would just like to add a "bool" to have a checkbox to select the grid rows (for example if I check line 1, line 3, line 7, I would add them to a matrix list).

But despite my research I am a little lost in the procedure to "add" a new data to a collection. 
Something like "foreach line > add this bool.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a "DataGridCheckBoxColumn" in your Datagrid columns definition :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Matrice}>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Check"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Absolutely awsome, it's exactly what i need. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your class matrix is what is presented to each row.

That becomes the datacontext for each row.

You would add a public bool property to Matrix and bind to that using a datagridcheckboxcolumn.

If Matrix is actually a model class and you cannot change it's properties then add another class. MatrixViewModel. Add properties match your model to that, plus the bool. Copy data from your model class to the viewmodel. If there are a lot of properties you could use reflection or automap.